# is a good idea to PyImport_ImportModule() in static variable?

Tags: python

With Python C API, it is a good idea to import a module in a static variable ?

```
static PyObject* typing=NULL;

void f() {
  if (typing==NULL) {
    typing=PyImport_ImportModule("typing");
  }
  ...
}
```

The reference counter was never decremented.

Answer (score 0):

There are potential issues in multi-threaded environment, at least because assignment is not guaranteed to be atomical.

Comment: But, Python never use the multi-thread when interpreting the bytecode. I can't have a race condition. The impact is in the lifecycle of the typing module. This instance can't be removed.

Comment: It may be an issue or may be not, depending on where do you use python API. If you embed python in your multi-threaded program, it might be. If you're writing native module without threads when it won't be an issue because of python global lock.